# Erlang process sending message

Tags: erlang

I understand that Erlang process message is sync.
When I do

Pid ! message

1. the sending message thread return right now
2. the sending message thread will confirm the message has put in the Pid's message queue and then return.

Which choice will the sending message thread do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your understanding might be wrong. Erlang message passing is **asynchronous**.
For example have a look [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-concurrency).
To answer your question then the option number **1** is what's happening here.

Comment: I Mean when the process deal with itself message queue. It is synchronous.

Comment: The sender doesn't necessarily interact directly with the receiver's mailbox. Even if they are on the same Erlang VM, there may be intermediate steps of transfer to avoid internal locks. The message passing is fully asynchronous, and doesn't even guarantee that the message has arrived in the target mailbox yet.

Comment: Yes, that is what I also meant with asynch. I have corrected my answer. ^^

Comment: @baotiao glad to have helped. Would you please accept the answer if you consider it right? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

In Erlang, message passing is asynchronous. The *sender* never blocks. Message delivery is *not* guaranteed. Caveats:

- If messaging a local process, then in practice, messages always arrive and do so very quickly.
- If messaging a remote process, then messages will be queued for sending. But due to the nature of TCP and distribution, it is not guaranteed that the message will be transferred and processed by the other party.

Answer (score 0):

I think

> the sending message thread return right now.

is right.

because `Pid ! message` just put the `message` into the message queue of process `Pid`. the process `Pid` will use `receive` to check its message queue. this is nothing with the sending process.

Comment: I agree with you, But when many processes want to send the message into the Pid's message queue. The processes battle for the right to put the message into the Pid's message queue. So some processes may wait a moment.